# Как узнать все сайты определенного провайдера?

Tags: веб-программирование, сеть, веб-сервер, сетевое-программирование, веб-сайт

У меня есть один не совсем стандартный но весьма необходимый запрос к провайдеру который необходим для моего сайта. Звонил несколько дней в поддержку. Со мой даже несколько раз соглашались, но потом откатывали обратно. И в итоге сказали что ничем помочь не могут.

Вот хочу узнать какие еще есть пользователи с сайтами у этого провайдера, чтобы подать что-то вроде коллективного запроса.

Какие для этого есть варианты?

Comment: Ну представьте себе, что они хотят сайты, о которых в приличном обществе не принято говорить. И они Вам никогда не расскажут о них, только если Вы не работаете в соответствующих органах и у Вас есть полномочия. Но может Вы скажите, ч какой целью Вам это нужно и, возможно, ответ будет сильно проще

Comment: шо?.. кто никогда не расскажет?

Answer (score 0):

В общем, нашел сам.

Заходим на сайт [2ip.ru](https://2ip.ru/). Ищем информацию по своему IP.

Там будет информация о провайдере, и конкретно ASN (не знаю, что это).

И там будут диапазоны IP и хостов.

Comment: Во-первых, если сайты не видны в публичном интернете, то здесь их видно не будет. Во-вторых, этот сервис врёт и даже публичные сайты показывает не все

Comment: шо значит "если сайты не видны в публичном интернете"? мне другие и не нужны. а какие еще бывают, кстати? "этот сервис врёт" - а кроме, слов есть ещё шото?

Comment: «а какие еще бывают, кстати?» — ну например с наркотиками и детской порнографией в каком-нибудь Tor...)

Comment: а Tor сайты висят на каком-то одном IP?)

Comment: Обычно да, но на каком именно, вы скорее всего не узнаете. Касательно «кроме слов» оно например по ASN почему-то не показывает мои собственные сайты, в частности к примеру git.andreymal.org

Comment: имеется ввиду поддомен? так это нормально, походу. у меня тоже штук 5, показывает только корень

Comment: Вот и нашёлся очень лёгкий способ скрыть свой сайт от этого сервиса - тупо использовать поддомен :) Этот факт окончательно подрывает доверие к этому сервису

Comment: от этого может и да, а вообще, нет. в целом, мою задачу (связь с админами серверов) он решает.

Comment: да и не думаю что он скрывает. он просто не отображает избыточную информацию